# convert string logic of rule array into workable HTML via javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of rules that are defined by their IDs. Here is an example:

```
[3001, 3002, 3004, 4005, 4006, 4007]
```

The tricky part is that I have a string that defines the logic that link these rules together. For example:

```
((0 AND (1 OR 2)) OR (3 AND 4 AND 5))
```

I am trying to create some simple HTML visualization of this logic. Where it would appear as so:

```
3001 and (3002 or 3004)
4005 and 4006 and 4007
```

The HTML on 2 lines there is just an example and not a requirement. The ultimate goal is to get it into some kind of array/object that would allow easy HTML manipulation.

Any ideas on how I can take the string and ultimately end up the some way of interacting with the rule array (eg. via HTML)?

Comment: please add some use cases with input and wanted output. what is a workable HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You could replace all numbers and use them as index for replacing with the assigned values.

```js
function replacer (array) {
    return function (i) {
        return array[i];
    };
}

var values = [3001, 3002, 3004, 4005, 4006, 4007],
    template = '((0 AND (1 OR 2)) OR (3 AND 4 AND 5))';

console.log(template.replace(/\d+/g, replacer(values)));
```

Comment: Interesting. Hadn't thought about this, but I like the simplicity. In my head, I was thinking about something more complex. For example, creating an array with each element representing a piece of logic. The OR at the top level would essentially be the delilmiter for each element. So ['(3001 and (3002 or 3004))' , '(4005 and 4006 and 4007)']. This would allow me to place each piece of logic on a separate line. Your solution is the first step in that process. Do you have any idea how I could split the top level OR only to create that array?